# Swipe hand icon animation with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, css-transforms

```css
html { background: #4F4F4F; }

.path {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(149, 147, 241, 0.5);
    border-radius: 40px;
    top: 28px;
    left: 78px;
}
.hand-icon {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/8556gm60/hand.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    animation: spin 2s infinite;
    transform-origin: 52% 62%;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(30deg); margin-left: 20px; }
    50% { transform: rotate(-15deg); margin-left: -20px; }
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); margin-left: 20px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="swipe">
    <div class="path"></div>
    <div class="hand-icon"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I have a good background in CSS, but I am quite new to CSS @keyframes, even though I cannot achieve what is in the screenshot above. The request is to make it animate infinitely and showing that you can drag the screen from the right to left. What I achieved you can see in the code attached.

How can I combine 2 animations and make the purple path animated as well on hand swipe?
Also why the first step is not animated? it is like jumping to 30deg, then it goes smooth. Tried to remake it with `100% { transform: rotate(0deg); margin-left: 20px; }` but id did not work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Mostly I would like to go with first animation from this [example](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/4139966/screenshots/8234016/media/56d442a2678fe13b85135f9decc6ddc6.gif)

Comment: Seems like your Fiddle code is not pointing to the right place

Comment: Please put your code as a runnable snippet direct into your question.See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry guys, I have updated the post. Was to late for me to check the links, seems that I have not saved it in the fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution achieves exactly what you want:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector(".path").style.animation = "swipe-dot 2s 0.5s infinite";
  
  document.querySelector(".hand-icon").style.animation = "swipe-hand 2s infinite";

}
```

```css
html { background: #4F4F4F; }

.path {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(149, 147, 241, 0.5);
    border-radius: 40px;
    top: 28px;
    left: 78px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.hand-icon {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/8556gm60/hand.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    transform-origin: 52% 62%;
}

@keyframes swipe-hand {
    25% { transform: translate(20px) rotate(30deg); }
    50% { transform: translate(-20px) rotate(-15deg); }
    100% { transform: translate(0px) rotate(0); }
}

@keyframes swipe-dot {
  12% {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 40px;
  }
  25% {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translate(-65px);
    width: 20px;
  }
  26% { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

```html
<div class="swipe">
    <div class="path"></div>
    <div class="hand-icon"></div>
</div>
```

And **yes** you need a bit of JS since we're waiting for an image to arrive to the browser before starting both animations

Regards

Comment: I see that in your example there is the same freezing like in my example, can it be corrected? or make it look more smooth? the one when hand it going from center to right

Comment: Sure. Corrected

Comment: The hand is now returning to its initial position, thus no more freezing/jumping effect

Comment: Thanks mate, now I understand where was my fault, and it was so simple :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just get the blueish dot to also have an animation which expands the width but keeps the right hand side in the same place.

This snippet assumes you don't want to change the HTML (e.g. put both in a container) so it does not use right: 0 to fix the right hand side.

```css
html {
  background: #4F4F4F;
}

.path {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(149, 147, 241, 0.5);
  border-radius: 40px;
  top: 28px;
  left: 78px;
  animation: expand 2s infinite;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    width: 20px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 78px;
    left: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 20px;
  }
}

.hand-icon {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/8556gm60/hand.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: spin 2s infinite;
  transform-origin: 52% 62%;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
    margin-left: -20px;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="swipe">
  <div class="path"></div>
  <div class="hand-icon"></div>
</div>
```